# Error Laravel al heredar los estilos de layouts.app

Tags: laravel

El error que tengo es que generé mediante estos comando las rutas y views para "Auth"

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

y al querer ver en el navegador las views de login y register no hereda los estilos de layout/app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Corriste los comandos npm?

Comment: probaré con estos

npm install
npm run dev

Comment: el error era que no tenía nodejs(no me acordaba que no lo había instalado y formatee mi disco duro)

Comment: Claro, esos dos. `npm install` para instalar las dependencias y `npm run dev` para compilar tus archivos sass y javascript. Necesitarás tener instalado Node y npm en tu sistema. Puedes leer más en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend) de Laravel.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda